# Explode a string where the explode condition is bunch of specific characters

Tags: php, explode

I'm looking for a way to explode a string. For example, I have the following string: (we don't count the beginning - **0x**)

> 0xa9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054368

which is actually an ETH transaction input. I need to explode this string into 3 parts. Imagine 1 bunch of zeros is actually a single space   and these spaces define the gates where the string should be exploded.

How can I do that?

Comment: `explode` splits a string using delimiters. Whereas you want substrings by index.

Comment: Just the normal [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) will probably do, because we have [mb_substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) for multibyte characters.

Comment: Does your PHP string consist of actual "raw" bytes, or does your string contain a hexadecimal representation of the binary content?

Comment: PHP strings are simple byte arrays, so… you're just looking at string slicing.

Comment: You have an `x` in the middle of your hexadecimal string. Is this intended? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

#### preg_split()

This function uses a regular expression to split a string.
So in this example at two or more `0` in a row:

```php
$arr = preg_split('/[0]{2,}/', $string);

print_r($arr);
echo PHP_EOL;
```

This will output the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a9059xbb
    [1] => fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d
    [2] => 54368
)
```

Be aware that you will have problems if a message itself has a `00` in it. Assuming it is used as a null-byte for "end of string", this will not happen, though.

#### preg_match()

This is an example using regular expressions. You can split at arbitrary points.

```php
$string = 'a9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054368';

print_r($string);
echo PHP_EOL;

$res = preg_match('/(.{4})(.{32})(.{32})/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
echo PHP_EOL;
```

This outputs:

```
a9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054368
Array
(
    [0] => a9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199a
    [1] => a905
    [2] => 9xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a
    [3] => 5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199a
)
```

As you can see `/(.{4})(.{32})(.{32})/` will find 4 bytes, then 32 and after that 32 again. Capturing groups are made with `()` around what you want to find. They appear in the `$matches` array (0 is always the whole string found).

In case you want to ignore certain parts you can express that as well:

```
/(.{4})9x(.{32}).{4}(.{32})/
```

This changes the found string:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d000
    [1] => a905
    [2] => bb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f
    [3] => a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d000
)
```

#### Links

PHP documentation for the mentioned functions:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Play around with the second regular expression using this demo:
https://regex101.com/r/pfZtH8/1

Comment: That's a pretty good explanation but I'm not sure if that is what I am actually looking for. I'll try to explain it in the simplest way possible - Imagine 1 bunch of zeros is actually a single space ` ` and these spaces define the gates where the string should be exploded.

Comment: Okay I'll add to the answer, that can be done as well. Please also update your question with that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always explode them at the same points (4 bytes(8 hexadecimal digits), 32 bytes(64 hexadecimal digits), 32 bytes(64 hexadecimal digits)), you could use substr().

```
$input = "0xa9059xbb000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054368";
$first = substr($input,2,8);
$second = substr($input,10,64);
$third = substr($input,74,64);

print_r($first);
print "<br>";
print_r($second);
print "<br>";
print_r($third);
print "<br>";
```

this outputs:

```
a9059xbb
000000000000000000000000fc7a5f48a1a1b3f48e7dcb1f23a1ea24199af4d0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000054368
```